# Selenium Chrome driver find text on the page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to load a web page in the Selenium Chrome driver and search a few texts on the loaded HTML page. I want to programmatically check if the search text is found or not. I found a way to search in the source code but couldn't find a way to search on the HTML page. XPath search would not work as I want to use the solution with different HTML pages. Could someone suggest how this can be done? I am using the Csharp language.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far with Page Source?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with Xpath. The following will return an array of any elements on the page with text `"text you want to search"`

```
driver.FindElements((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "text you want to search"]'));
```

Or, the following will grab any elements *containing* `"my text"`:

```
driver.FindElements((By.XPATH, '//*[text()[contains(.,'my text')]]'));
```

You can then find the length of that array, or interact with the elements specifically. As long as you are just searching for that text, I think this should work on any web page.

Comment: Your solution works but not for all pages. Could you please check this URL: https://www.ishares.com/529/portfolios/price-and-performance-all-class-a?siteEntryPassthrough=true&locale=en_US&userType=individual.  I tried google chrome Xpath search it shows result with the "Contains" method but when I tried from the CSharp code it return null. Below is my CSharp code: List<IWebElement> lstwebElements = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[text()[contains(.,'"+ txtKeyword1.Text + "')]]")));